# Passing angular js value to another page showing {{emi}} value using php

Tags: php, angularjs, html, phpmyadmin

I am using angularjs for getting values what I enter like:

```
<div ng-app="">
<select class="form-control" ng-model="emi" id="emimonthly">
    <option value="5">5th</option>
    <option value="10">10th</option>
</select> 
<?php $_SESSION['emidate']= "{{emi}}"; ?>
```

This is working in this page, i want to call session to another page if calling session it shows as `{{emi}}`

What i did wrong?